# Create project folder Buildengine

Tags: c#, buildengine

When I am creating one project file by code using the BuidEngine, Does anybody know..

1. how to add project folders?
2. how to add one builditem to the created folder?

.

```
var project = new Project();
project.Load(ProjectFile.FullName, ProjectLoadSettings.IgnoreMissingImports);
//Create project folder
var buildItem = project.AddNewItem(itemName, fileName);
//add file to folder
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by project folder? Won't specifying `filename` like `Folder\File1` do the trick?